# Download de arquivo no IOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, download

Galera estou a pouco tempo programando para IOS utilizando a linguagem SWIFT.

Preciso fazer download de um arquivo da web, estou utilizando NSURLSessionConfiguration, mas esse objeto só funciona para IOS 8+. E eu quero que o app rode nos dispositivos com IOS 7+. Alguém sabe como posso contornar isso?

```
func download(url: NSURL)
{
    self.url = url

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier(url.absoluteString)
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        let task = session.downloadTaskWithURL(url)
        task.resume()
    } else {
        //Tratar para fazer download para versão 7
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Segundo a documentação, `NSURLSession` e `NSURLSessionConfiguration` funcionam no iOS 7.

Fonte:

[NSURLSession Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/)

[NSURLSessionConfiguration Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/)